# Measuring the speed of a NIC

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a couple of boards (but I think the question would be the same if they were PCs- except maybe since they are boards running linux, I would like to run console tools), connected to the internet through wire.

Now, one of them is connected the ethernet port (as expected).
The other one, is connected with a converter (not sure of the correct terminology) that attaches to the USB port and then to a ethernet cable.

I would like to measure the speed (and make basic operation check) of both.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you run software on these devices? And are you looking at 'line' speed or 'actual' speeds in use?

Comment: Yes, I can. And I am looking at the  difference in speed (if any) between those two configurations. I don't know the difference between line and actual speed

Comment: "*I don't know the difference between line and actual speed*" -- You seem to be confusing "*actual speed*" with throughput. The data on the wire travel at a fixed speed. But there can be idle time between frames (e.g. TCP protocol waiting for ACK response). When you calculate an *average* of data per time interval, you end up with a throughput number that is less than the actual/fixed speed.

Answer (score 2):

Well there's a few different approaches to this - I'll be using [ethtool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethtool) to get 'basic' information about a device, and iperf to check its actual speed. I'm using a connection I 'know' is slower (its via homeplug) to show the difference. In theory with a USB connection you *might* experience bottlenecks

Firstly of course, you need to know some information about the device and the ip address it has - `ip addr` does this

I'd then use ethtool to get information about the adaptor

```
geek@box31:~$ ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
        Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        master-slave cfg: preferred slave
        master-slave status: slave
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        MDI-X: Unknown
netlink error: Operation not permitted
        Link detected: yes
```

The important line here is `Speed: 1000Mb/s` - or what I'd refer to as line speed. *Practically* you're unlikely to hit the 'full' speed of this. This is the *fastest* your hardware *could* go. In the home user setting, most systems are gigabit, or fast (100baseT) ethernet, though we're starting to see multigig Nics up to 10Gig on home systems now.

To demonstrate this, I'm using [iperf3](https://iperf.fr) - You run a server on another system,with `iperf3 -s` and connect to the server with something like  `iperf3 -c ip_of_server -t 10`

This'll give you an output like this

```
iperf3: interrupt - the client has terminated
geek@box31:~$ iperf3 -c 192.168.2.121 -t 10
Connecting to host 192.168.2.121, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.2.86 port 44846 connected to 192.168.2.121 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  12.1 MBytes   101 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  10.6 MBytes  88.7 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  10.3 MBytes  86.7 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  10.5 MBytes  87.7 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  10.2 MBytes  85.7 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  10.9 MBytes  91.2 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  10.5 MBytes  87.7 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  10.2 MBytes  85.2 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  10.3 MBytes  86.2 Mbits/sec    0    351 KBytes
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  10.5 MBytes  88.2 Mbits/sec    5    173 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   106 MBytes  88.8 Mbits/sec    5             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   104 MBytes  87.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

I'll leave exact interpretation as a exercise to the reader *but* in this case, while both ends of my connection *are* capable of a full gigabit connection, you'll see my speeds are slower.

With a direct point to point connection or one through a router or switch that's capable of full gigabit, you'd see speeds closer to, but not equal to line speeds. Iperf is also *pretty* low overhead so with a 'real world' protocol like http or https, you may see *small* differences in speed.

There's other factors as well, such as packet size, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.